# Temporal tables missing data when migrating from SQL Server to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate a SQL Server 2016 database to SQL Azure via Data Migration Assistant. All the database tables are created, including the temporal ones, but only the temporal ones are missing data. Both main and history tables are completely empty.

Does anyone know if I have to do something special here to get this data filled in?  Or do I unfortunately have to move this data over manually?

Comment: How many tables - perhaps you can set system_versioning = off for all first and then re-apply it after migrating? Presumably you have a process that does this for maintenace and rolling deletes etc since that's not automatically handled in 2016.

Comment: I think there are around 6 to 10 versioned tables.  I'm just surprised Microsoft's tool doesn't do anything with it automatically.  I know I can work around it manually if I have to, but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific to your scenario, if migration is the only concern, you can use SSMS to migrate the complete database with some easy steps. I tried it and there is no issue with the Temporal tables. All the temporal tables with data are migrating.

Follow the below steps:

1. Right click on the database you want to migrate. Select **Task** and from dropdown options select **Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database**

[image]

2. Click on Next on pop-up window. On the very next window you will get options to connect your Azure SQL Server. Provide your Azure SQL server name, server credentials and click on **Connect**.

[image]

Provide the name for new database that will be creating in Azure SQL Server. Fill the Azure SQL Database settings as per your requirement. Click on **Next**.

[image]

Lastly, you will get a summary of all the settings you have done. Click on **Finish** to migrate the database.

Once your database migrated successfully, you will get summary with **Operation Complete** message. Click on **Close**. Your database has been migrated.

Check for the new database on Azure Portal and verify the data.

[image]